# How to access the product list from Sage Line 50?

Tags: c#, .net, sage-line-50

I need to pull the product list from Sage Line 50. Is there any way to do this without having to spend £1500 on joining the developer program?

I only need to read data, I do not need to put data back into Sage. I've seen the odd mention of an ODBC.Net driver for Sage, but I cannot find any tutorials or examples of how this is done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this Point of Sale (POS), or another product in the Line 50 Suite?

Comment: The Sage Accounts package is what I need the product list for.

Comment: Here's some more ideas about connection strings etc, http://networkprogramming.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!D79966C0BAAE2C7D!287.entry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any extras for the ODBC driver in Line 50. It is ages since I did this, but if you are using Visual Studio for instance, you should be able to set up a data connection using a Microsoft ODBC Data Source in Server Exlplorer. If you have Line 50 installed, it should show up as a DSN. It is only when you want to write back that you need to pay more, you should be able to see the products, ledgers, etc. in read only.